# Can I omit "had" if it is repeated too many times in a paragraph?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, past-tense

Example:

> I’d heard about this mystery before. However, **I'd** only thought it
>   as a ghost story; something you'd tell around a campfire.

Maybe I'm mistaken but the paragraph sounds better without the *'d*:

> I’d heard about this mystery before. However, **I** only thought it
>   as a ghost story; something you'd tell around a campfire.

Is this a common practice? When do I know when I can omit *had* and when I cannot?

Comment: the third contraction isn't *had* but *would* i.e. something you would tell around a campfire. AND  I'd only thought **of** it

Answer (score 2):

The 'had' (or 'd) surely indicates that it's what had been thought *up to that point*. After which the opinion was altered. Without the 'd, it doesn't carry the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> "I’d heard about this mystery before"

Here you have to use de past perfect tense to express an action that happened in the past and was complete before a second action (to think of it).

> "I only thought of it as a ghost story."

And here you just use the past simple tense. It isn't a matter of omitting the 'd but using the past simple.